# .contains() does not work with standard input in java?

Tags: java, string

I am using `.contains()` to check `standard input`, but it seems not to work for me. For example even if I put `hi there` as standard input I get:

```
hi there 
nobody likes to eat peas is true
```

I am expecting to get in addition:

```
hi there is true
```

```java
public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inp = sc.next();
        String fixed = "nobody likes to eat peas";
        if (inp.contains("hi there")){
            System.out.println(inp + " is " + true);
        }
        if (fixed.contains(" to eat ")){
            System.out.println(fixed + " is " + true);
        }
    }
```

**My Question is:** does standard input not work with the `.contains()` method even though the standard input should match the input using `.contains()` or is my code wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanners work by treating the input as if it is split into chunks, where in between each chunk (called a 'token') is the delimiter.

Out of the box, 'any sequence of whitespace' is the delimiter. So, `inp` couldn't possibly contain `hi there` - after all, if you fed that input straight to the program, the first token is `hi`. That's all that `inp` would contain. A second call to `next()` would then return `there`.

It sounds like you intend for the scanner to treat entire lines as the chunks, and newline symbols as the delimiter.

All you have to do, is tell scanner about it, and all will be well:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("\r?\n");
// rest of your code as normal
```

NB: \r?\n is regexp for 'an optional CR followed by a required LF'. This catches both unix/macosx style newlines (\n) as well as windows style newlines (\r\n).

Comment: Wouldn't `nextLine()` be more usual?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-  nextLine() and next() can't be used together, though. If you ever call next() or nextInt(), then you're lost - you could 'eat the newline' with nextLine(), but if the user is asked for 2 int inputs which you read with 2x nextInt() and you 'eat the newline', your app is broken. As a rule I suggest forgetting nextLine() exists. If you want that, update the delimiter. Or if you just care about lines, There's other methods like Files.lines and friends.